# Why do the Stoney units of time, length, and mass differ with the Planck units by the squareroot of the fine structure constant?

Tags: units, physical-constants

The [natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units) of Planck and Stoney differ by the inverse of the finestructure constant.

For example, the Stoney-mass is:

$$m_s=\sqrt{\frac{k_e e^2}{G}}=  1.85921×10^{-9} kg,$$

where $k_e$ is Coulomb's constant, $G$ the gravitational constant, and $c$ the speed of light.

In contrast, the Planck mass is given by:

$$m_p=\sqrt{\frac{{h}c}{2\pi G}}=.2.176×10^{-8}kg $$

Now, $\frac{1.85921×10^{-9}}{2.176×10^{-8}} =\frac{1}{11.7},$

which is the square root of $\frac{1}{137}$.

Hoe van we extract this from both units? Just dividing the units?

Comment: *Just dividing the units?* Have you tried doing that? Do you know the formula for the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant)?

Comment: What are you attempting to do? This seems to be a choice, i.e. no interesting meaning behind it

Comment: @Ghoster I see I forgot to put it in! Yes, I know it. There is no k_e in it.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I just wonder why they differ by the FSC

Comment: @Ghoster Oh wait. Isn',t k_e=1/4pixepsilon?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Yes, you are right. It's indeed without meaning.

Comment: Yes, $k_e=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$.

Comment: @Ghoster Then the question is answered already.... Thanks!

Comment: If you feel your question is already answered trivially in comments could you please close your question (do not delete it as there is a penalty for deletions).  It's best not to leave open questions which will never to answered or had a trivial error in them.